# why are my shared preference values being overwritten?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**I want to** store different values on different events in the shared preferences.

eg. i have a toggle button which sets `profilevisibility` to On and off, so if i check the toggle button, it should store the `profilevisibility` value as 1.

now i also have another toggle button there which sets `matchPreference` to on and off, so if i uncheck this toggle button, it should set the `matchPreference` value as 0.

**what happens is**, when i set `profileVisibility` to ON, it does saves the value as 1 but, now if i set the `MatchPreference` to OFF, it also saves the values as 0, but overwrites other values too..

**This is my code called on OnCreate in the Activity**

```
HashMap<String, String> profileVisibility = session.getProfileVisibility();
profilevibility_value =profileVisibility.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_VISIBILITY);

HashMap<String, String> discoverability = session.getDiscoverablity();
discoverability_value = discoverability.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_DISCOVER);

HashMap<String, String> listmatches = session.getListMatches();
listmatches_value = listmatches.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_MATCH);
```

**Values get overwritten for all three variable here, why?**

These are my methods for storing and fetching values in my session manager

```
public static final String KEY_VISIBILITY = "1";
public static final String KEY_DISCOVER = "1";
public static final String KEY_MATCH = "1";
public void StoreProfileVisiblity(String male){

        editor.putString(KEY_VISIBILITY, male);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void StoreDiscoverablity(String status){

        editor.putString(KEY_DISCOVER, status);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void StoreListMatches(String match){

        editor.putString(KEY_MATCH, match);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getProfileVisibility(){

        HashMap<String, String> mpv = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mpv.put(KEY_VISIBILITY, pref.getString(KEY_VISIBILITY, null));
        return mpv;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getDiscoverablity(){

        HashMap<String, String> dv = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dv.put(KEY_DISCOVER, pref.getString(KEY_DISCOVER, null));
        return dv;
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getListMatches(){

        HashMap<String, String> lmv = new HashMap<String, String>();
        lmv.put(KEY_MATCH, pref.getString(KEY_MATCH, null));
        return lmv;
    }
```

Comment: What are there values in UserSessionManager.KEY_VISIBILITY, UserSessionManager.KEY_DISCOVER and UserSessionManager.KEY_MATCH?

Comment: Those values will be set from activity. Eg. session.StoreDiscoverability("1"). By default i have set everything as 1, if its On then its 1 or else its set as 0

Comment: My question was - what did you assigned on those keys?

Comment: Thats what i usually use for storing my sessions. can you suggest another best possible option?

Comment: What @skabir was asking is, can you post the part from `UserSessionManager` where you define the 3 constants you are using: `KEY_VISIBILITY`, `KEY_DISCOVER` and `KEY_MATCH`

Comment: @skabir i edited sessionmanger code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign different value for each of those keys. Like...

```
public static final String KEY_VISIBILITY = "KEY_VISIBILITY";
public static final String KEY_DISCOVER = "KEY_DISCOVER";
public static final String KEY_MATCH = "KEY_MATCH";
```

I think, it will solve your problem.

Comment: OMG what a mistake... well yea that helped :)